# A natural number equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

For what values of $n$ the equation $x^2 - (2n+1)xy + y^2 + x = 0$ has no solution in natural numbers ? (for $n=1$ it has a trivial solution).

Comment: It's important to state whether zero is considered a natural number in this context, since $(0,0)$ will always be an integer solution. (I removed the algebraic geometry tag since it's a stretch to apply that to a single diophantine equation.)

Comment: @hardmath ok, $0$ is not natural !

Comment: @Jash, " there seems to be no general agreement about whether to include 0 in the set of natural numbers." : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalNumber.html

Comment: Well here's something which may or may not help: $x$ must divide $y^2$ (and, assuming I did my algebra right, if $y$ is a multiple of $x$ then $n=1$)

Comment: @Sp3000: does your algebra support solutions arising from $n=-2$?

Comment: @Sp3000, also $y|(x^2+x)$

Comment: @abiessu Hm, if I let $y=kx$ I only seem to get $n = 1$. How did you get $n = -2$?

Comment: @Sp3000: I take it back, $y$ cannot be negative under the problem statement.

Comment: $y$ is not divisible by $x$. $y^2$ is divisible by $x$. Actually, $x$ must be a square - see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Letting $m=2n+1$ just for brevity, we see that:

$$(x-y)^2 = x((m-2)y-1)\\
(x+y)^2 = x((m+2)y-1)$$

Now, note that if $p|x$, then $p|x+y$ so $p|y$ and therefore $p\not\mid (m\pm2)y-1$.

Therefore, $x,(m-2)y-1$ are relatively prime, so must be perfect squares. Similarly, $(m+2)y-1$ must be a perfect square.

In the original equation, we can substitute $x=x_0^2$ and $y=x_0y_0$ (necessarily, $x_0|y$) and dividing out the common factors to get:

Substituting, this means we need to solve:

$$x_0^2 -mx_0y_0 + y_0^2 + 1 = 0$$

This has an integer solution if and only if $D = (my_0)^2 - 4(y_0^2+1) = (m^2-4)y_0^2 - 4$ is a perfect square, which means if and only if we have  solution to:

$$U^2 - (m^2-4)V^2 = -4$$

Mike Bennett below in comments asserts this does not have a solution except when $m=\pm 3$, which coincides with $n=-2,1$.

This is not hard to reduce this to the equation: $$W^2-(m^2-4)Z^2=-1$$

The continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt{m^2-4}$, when $m>3$ is odd, can be written as:

$$\sqrt{m^2-4} = \left[m-1,\overline{1,\frac{m-3}{2},2,\frac{m-3}{2},1,2(m-1)},\dots\right]$$

Since the length of the repetition is even, there is no solution to $W^2-(m^2-4)Z^2=-1$.

Comment: Nice argument. How about the converse !?

Comment: Also, $(n^2-1)x-1+y$ should be a perfect square.

Comment: The case $n=7$ demonstrates the lack of sufficiency. If one just considers the discriminant of the original equation with respect to $y$, one is led to Pell equations without solutions, provided $n>1$.

Comment: Yeah, I think the existence of a root of $U^2-(m^2-4)V^2=-4$ is necessary and sufficient. @MikeBennett

Comment: Precisely correct. And, for $m > 3$ (even or odd), this equation has no solutions...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews May I ask how do you reduce to $W^2 - (m^2-4)V^2 = -1$ ?

Comment: @AA If $U,V$ are both even you are done. Otherwise, $U,V$ must be both odd (if $m$ is odd.) You divide $U+V\sqrt{m^2-4}$ by $m\pm \sqrt{m^2-4}$. You then prove that *one* of the two resulting quotions is in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{m^2-4}]$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for your comment but still I do not understand.

Comment: @AA Can you be more specific about what you don't understand. Do you know what is meant by $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{D}]$, and what the "norm" is in that ring?

Comment: @AA The briefest reason is that if $m,U,V$ are odd such that $U^2-(m^2-4)V^2=-4$ then $$(W,Z)=\left(\frac{m\pm V(m^2-4)}{4},\frac{U\pm Vm}{4}\right)$$ is a solution to $W^2-(m^2-4)Z^2=-1$, where the $\pm$ is chosen so that $U\pm Vm$ is divisible by $4$. You can easily show that $W,Z$ are integers.

Comment: @AA But that comment is "magic" - what's really happening is that I'm dividing in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{m^2-4}]$ to get the $(W,Z)$.